# Is there much of an anti-cookie movement anymore?

Tags: cookies

I'm not sure whether this belongs on StackOverflow or on ServerFault, so I've picked SO for as first go.

A number of years ago, there was a highly visible discussion about mis-use of HTTP cookies, leading to various cookie filtering proxys and eventually to active cookie filtering in browsers like Firefox and Opera. Even now, Google will admit that currently about 7% of end-users will reject their tracking cookies, which is quite a lot, actually.

I still vett all cookies that get set in my browser. I have for years. I personally do not know anyone else who does this, but it has given me a few interesting insights into web tracking. For instance, there are many many more sites using Google Analytics than there were even two years ago. And there are still sites (extremely few, fortunately) which malfunction hideously if you don't let them set cookies. But advertisers in particular are still setting cookies to track your way across the web.

So is there much of an anti-cookie movement anymore? Has anyone tried to take Google to task for setting so many with Analytics? Is anyone trying to vilify sites like Ebay and PayPal who use a dodgy cross-site cookie to let you login?

Or am I making too much of a stupidly small problem?

Comment: Cookies in general help a lot more than they hurt. I heard Opera 10 is planning to support a client side database. This would basically be organized cookies. You're being tracked all the time anyway nowadays, that cookies in general don't really pose much of a threat to your anonymity online anymore.

Comment: I do the same thing, vetting all cookies before I let Firefox save them.  At some sites it's a real pain.  If only there were something for cookies as powerful as NoScript, "temporarily allow" and so on.  I'm interest to see if you get any answers where people say it's a non-issue and we're silly to pay attention to this.

Comment: I admit a lot of the problems are site a.b.com calling content from d.e.com and d.e.com expects to be allowed to set cookies. No: IMO that should only be the right of a.b.com.

Comment: I've taken a white list approach to cookies for years. It's really no hassle as you only have to allow each site once. If Firefox didn't allow this option, I'd settle for blocking all third-party cookies, but it's quite easy to just block everything and only let through what actually needs to run. I take the same approach to Javascript with NoScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also one of the hold-outs who doesn't automatically accept cookies.  I do appreciate sites that need fewer, and I am more likely to return to those sites and allow cookies from them in the future.

That said, I do think that being vigilant about cookies is not (rationally) worth the effort.  (In other words, I expect I will keep doing what I'm doing because it makes me feel better, even though I don't have evidence of commensurate tangible benefit.)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, there are other ways to block these annoyances. [Rick752's EasyList](http://easylist.adblockplus.org/) has the EasyPrivacy list, which blocks most of them with no work at all other than adding the subscription once to [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/). [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) can (with a little configuration, mostly removing some misguided entries on the default whitelist) easily block the ones which depend on JavaScript.

That said, I set up my browser to empty all the cookies on logout. Then they can track you only for the duration of a session, which will be short unless you tend to keep your browser open for a long time (or use the session save/restore all the time).

If you use Flash, know that it also has a kind of cookies, and the interface to manage them is most probably poorer than your browser's.

Answer (score 1):

There's always people who misunsderstand cookies - on both sides.  Ultimatey, it's up to the browsers to properly identify the sites for cookies.  As long as the site's being set properly and the browser's respecting that, it's just not much of a problem.  I think thta, with the increased use of web toolkits that take care of the programmatic details (and better, slightly more security-conscious browsers), it's not much of an issue now for end-users.

Beyond that, the proliferation of DHTML and XML-based partial-page-loading mechanisms (as well as database-backends and similar), the need to track session between stateless pages is reduced now.  Your web app can very easily keep state without the need for cookies, and that may well have partially been driven by the number of [generally misinformed] end-users who blocked cookies all together.

In shorter words: "IMHO, no".

Answer (score 1):

I gave up both as user and developer.

As a user the convenience of staying logged into sites is just too tempting, the pain of some sites not working too annoying. And I'm not that sensitive about my privacy, so I stopped caring and let all cookies through.

As a developer I always try to be as RESTful as possible, but I don't know any decent way of handling authentication without cookies. HTTP Basic Auth is just too broken, I can't assume HTTPS all the time and mangling URLs is painful and inelegant. What's left is form-based authentication with cookies. So my applications have one auth cookie -- I don't need any more than that, but that by itself requires the user to have cookies on if they want to authenticate themselves. Maybe OpenID and other federated identity services might fix that one day, but at the moment I can't rely on any of these yet.

Comment: One cookie I can accept. Amongst other things, it shows me the website has a decent session layer. Setting five shows me it does not.

Answer (score 1):

My biggest annoyance with cookies is that I want to block Analytics cookies but at the same time I need to login to analytics to manage some customer sites. As far as I can tell they are the same cookie (in fact it may be the same cookie across all google services).

I really don't trust the Google cookie. They were apparently one of the first large companies to set cookie expiration to 2038 (the maximum) and their business model is almost entirely advertising based (targeted advertising at that). I suspect they know more about the day-to-day online activities and interests of people than any other government or organisation on the planet.

That's not to say it's all evil or anything but that really is a lot of trust to be given one entity. They may claim it's all anonymised but I'm pretty sure that claim would be hard to verify. At any rate there is no guarantee that this data won't be stolen, legally acquired or otherwise misused at some future point for other purposes.

It isn't impossible that one day this kind of profiling could be used to target people for more serious things than ads. How hard would it be for some future Hitler to establish the IP addresses, bank accounts, schools, employers, club memberships etc of some arbitary class of person for incarceration or worse?

So my answer is that this is not a small problem and history has already taught us many times over what can happen when you start classifying and tracking people. Cookies are not the only means but they are certainly a part of the problem and I recommend blocking them and clearing at every convenient opportunity.

Comment: The actual analytics cookies are per site, that is, they are "first party cookies". Google gets that right, at least. Omniture used to serve third-party cookies, but they migrated to first-party cookies a few years ago. Most advertisers set third-party cookies, however.

Answer (score 0):

Every now and again I clear all my cookies. It's a pain as I then have to login to sites again (or set preferences) but this is also a good test as to whether either me or my browser can remember the login details..